# How to change chart colors in Pages 5?

Tags: applications, pages, iwork

I cannot change the individual colors in my charts. Under "Chart Colors" there is only this list of 12 predefined color swatches called "fill sets". Most of them are ugly. Not being able to change individual colors means no ability to add the company's brand colors to documents and that sort of thing. How can I change the colors of my chart?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out! One must click on an individual point on the graph or chart and then go to the Style tab under Fill and change that. It will change the color for all the data points in that column.

Not intuitive at first, but definitely easy once you know about it.